# SSRS Stored Procedure (Timing Out?). Using too many Linked Servers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We are using one shared data source `ds1` that connects to a server `main_server` which holds all the stored procedures to generate our reports.

One of the stored procedures `usp1` simply executes another stored procedure on another server `another_server`:

```
exec another_server.another_database.dbo.usp1
```

When I execute `usp1` on `main_server`, everything works fine.  It runs at almost the same speed as if I had just gone to `another_server` and executed from there.... Which is what I expected...

However, when I try to run the report from our report server, it fails.  When I watch it run, it almost immediately goes into suspended mode and stays there.

We have all of our timeouts set to 40 minutes, so that shouldn't be our issue, since the report runs in 15.  Any thoughts?

Thanks...

Comment: One of my colleagues has recently configured an SSRS instance and he also had problems connecting to a remote SQL instance to report from. I believe the answer he found, but didn't use, was to set the execution account on the report.

Comment: If the report's query runs for 15 minutes on main_server, then it sounds like a lot of rows are returned. Perhaps it's the generation of the HTML in SSRS that is taking a lot of time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the account reporting services uses to run the report doesnt have the correct access or rights to run an sp on another server?

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue, given that, for testing, I am logging in to SQL Server Management Studio using the same credentials used in the data source's connection string, with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

With linked servers your stored procedure may copy ALL the data it needs before doing any joins.

Check out:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/06/30/linked-server-performance-heterogeneous-databases.aspx